# converting each array value ias object in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my array:

```
var country = ["US(+1)","IND(+91)"];
```

And i want to convert my array in this below format:

```
country = [
    {
      title: "US(+1)",      
    },
    {
      title: "IND(+91)",    
    }
  ]
```

word `title`  should be same for each array value.
with this code  am trying to get my expected result as above

```
 var obj = country.reduce(function(o, val) { o['title'][] = val; return o; }, {});
```

But my output is comes like this as below: only last index is taking place

`{"title":"IND(+91)"}` this is wrong output which i dont want

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: my out put is like this which I dont want {"title":"IND(+91)"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to do it with `reduce` but it's much easier to use `map`:

```js
var country = ["US(+1)","IND(+91)"];
var obj = country.map(function(c){return {title:c}});

console.log("country:", country);
console.log("obj:", obj);
```

`map` is for when you want to turn an array of things into another array of things, and `reduce` is when you want to turn an array of things into just a single thing.

Comment: To expand on this, note that in general, `map` is for when you want to turn an array of things into another array of things, and `reduce` is when you want to turn an array of things into just a single thing

Comment: Be sure to use markdown indentation, not back ticks, to wrap your code so that it shows up properly.

Comment: @Hamms I just put your remark into the answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

```
var country = ["US(+1)","IND(+91)"];
```

I would use a more descriptive word since it is a list of countries.

```
var countries = ["US(+1)","IND(+91)"];
```

But to answer your question, to manipulate an array into a new array, I like to use the array.map method:

```
var objects = countries.map(function(country){ return { title: country } });
```

Here is the documentation for map:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control